# Why This is Slower - Find Max Between 2 Numbers without if

Tags: c, algorithm, performance

An assignment - find the maximum of two numbers **without `if`** and with the **highest efficiency**. (My instructor says that `if` ruins  efficiency and makes the program slower.)

So I did this:

```
long num1=555527778658567767676735; // Random Number
long num2=34277745575656835; // Another Random Number
long big; // The Biggest Number

// I KNOW THIS IS NOT SOLVING THE PROBLEM
big = (num1 - num2) - (num1 > num2) * (num1 - num2); // The Code That Is Faster - 2.791 seconds for 10B Times

big = num1 - (num2 > num1) * (num1 - num2); // The Slower Line Of Code - 3.069 second for 10B Times
```

My question is why this - `big = (num1 - num2) - (num1 > num2) * (num1 - num2);` is faster than this - `big = num1 - (num2 > num1) * (num1 - num2);`

When in the second line I don't do this subtracting `(num1 - num2)` and instead I do this `num1` only; isn't it supposed to be faster without another "thing" to calculate?

Comment: Why do you think it is faster? Did you measure? If yes, please provide your measurements. Also, please consider looking at the assembly output.

Comment: Try looking at the generated assembly. Also, don't discount the optimization abilities of the compiler, modern top-compilers are very good at optimization, using `if` might be more effective with optimizations.

Comment: @BenSteffan Where Can I Find The Assembly Output?

Comment: Don't Write Sentences With Initial Caps As It's Cumbersome To Read.

Comment: I'd be astonished if anything was significantly faster than `(a >= b) ? a : b`, and I'd be astonished if the equivalent written with `if` was slower.

Comment: Why would anyone teach that conditionals ruin efficiency? What is the value in that?  I guess it follows that you shouldn't ever write any code because it's always going to run slower than no code at all.

Comment: Either OP has misunderstood the teacher, or the teacher is not to be trusted.

Comment: It's possible that on the processor level (num1-num2) is evaluated only once and stored in a single register, basically reused for the second part of `big = (num1 - num2) - ...`. On the other hand this should also be true for `num1` which i.e. their behavior could be the same. Maybe measure the time when using something else for the first part of the first expression? Like `big = (num1 + num2) - ...`.

Comment: the compiler is smarter than you thought. Just use `max = a > b ? a : b` and it'll use branchless code if necessary. And there may be more efficient non-branch solutions like [this](https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#IntegerMinOrMax)

Comment: Also, `if`s in general affect performance. They branch the program execution and cause stalls in pipelining. But yes, they're also heavily optimized on both the compiler and instruction level. So in principle a simple `if` should be like there was no `if` at all.

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc "On some **rare machines** where branching is very expensive and no condition move instructions exist, the above expression might be faster than the obvious approach"

Comment: `long num1=555527778658567767676735;`?? Are you running on a 128-bit CPU? That's bigger than 2^63-1.

Comment: I want to test with the worst case @lurker

Comment: Sure, but that's not even a valid `long` value on a 64-bit machine. It doesn't fit. How did you come up with `555527778658567767676735`? That's something like 79 bits.

Comment: You typically generate the assembly code with the `-S` option to the compiler and look for the assembler output from compiling `source.c` in the file `source.s` (unless you use `-o somename`, in which case look in `somename`).

Comment: Does the first calculation reliably produce the bigger number?  In my testing, I got `0` when `num1` is bigger than `num2` and negative numbers when `num1` is smaller than `num2`.  I'm not clear if this is what is meant by the shouted comment "I know this is not solving the problem".

Comment: I mean that ignore what the code does and focus on why it's slower when the second line is less thing to do

Comment: @RazLuvaton `num1 - num2` may overflow and signed integer overflow is _undefined behavior_ (UB).  Do you care if the the result is wrong for some combinations of `long`?  What is the greatest and least value `long` may have on you platform?

Comment: that random number is not the worst case, it's the worst test ever

Comment: Why? @LưuVĩnhPhúc

Comment: @lurker just going through my old questions and damn, I was stupid as hell 

Comment: @RazLuvaton no worries. We've all been there but not all willing to admit it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is due to the compiler. The process happens in stage 2.
Basically compiler for optimization sets `a=num1-num2` and stores it in its memory.
So now it has calculated a, only once and simply puts it in the statement.

```
big = a - (n1>n2)*a;
```

This is either `big = a` or `big = 0`, performs 3 calculations in total . One for num1-num2, other for n1>n2 and third for (a-1*a) or (a - 0*a)

The other one:

```
big = n1 - (n1>n2)*(n1-n2)
```

has the following :

1. n1>n2 =a
2. n1 - n2 =b
3. a*b =c
4. n1 - c

The previous one had 3 calculations and this one has 4.
The time will be better in the 1st one especially since large numbers are being dealt with, otherwise the time difference should be negligible.
Also, note if you run the time tests again and again even for one of the two calculations mentioned by you, you'll see variations in the time taken. So please note that your observation of time difference is not completely absolute, however the first one will be faster than the second one nonetheless.

Edit 1: Also, note in first statement `if (n1>n2)` is false,i.e, 0, then it simply becomes `big = a - 0*a` ,here, compiler doesn't perform multiplication also, since it sees a 0 in the statement and muliplication operand. After which doesn't it doesn't perform the subtraction also and is simply written in memory as `big=a` which would give a faster result as well
`if (n1>n2)` is true , the same holds as it becomes, `big=a-1*a` where the compiler sees the `1` and eliminates it in the multiplicand operand and simply writes then doesn't need to perform multiplication and simply writes it as `a -a`. The **main** portion , when it does `a-a` it gets converted into bits first then finally after subtraction, gives , 00000, now these bits do no be converted back to the decimal 0 again by the compiler and can simply be written as 0. *However* for n1- ()*(n1-n2)` , this number will turn out to be something negative, basically after getting the final result in bits, conversion to decimal will also take place.

Answer (score 3):

Here is my guess:

The compiler simplifies the expression:

```
(num1 - num2) - (num1 > num2) * (num1 - num2)

(1 - (num1 > num2)) * (num1 - num2)
```

finally

```
(num1 <= num2) * (num1 - num2)
```

Which would indeed be faster than

```
num1 - (num2 > num1) * (num1 - num2)
```

Thanks to @SirGuy, here is the assembly from clang:

```
max2(long, long):                              # @max2(long, long)
        xor     eax, eax
        sub     rdi, rsi
        cmovg   rax, rdi
        sub     rdi, rax
        mov     rax, rdi
        ret
```

This seems to mean: take diff of num1 and num2, keep it in rdi. If it's > 0, put diff into rax, else leave rax as 0. The return value is rdi - rax, which would be 0 or the diff, depending on what was moved to rax. So, pretty close to `(num1 <= num2) * (num1 - num2)` - just done with subtraction rather than multiplication :)

Comment: `num1 - num2` may overflow and signed integer overflow is _undefined behavior_ (UB).  Perhaps OP does not care if a fast solution only works for select `long`.

Comment: @chux OP says that he knows that the code he wrote does not do the right thing. He is just puzzled why the seemingly more complex code is faster.

Comment: The compiler does not do what you said it does. It can't make such  decisions. It infact boils down to how compiler does optimization and then number of calculations to print final result.

Comment: Well, the computer certainly simplified the expression as part of the optimization, even if not exactly the way I suggested.